# Avoid circular dependency when storing revisions?

Tags: mysql, database-design, circular-dependency

The following is a very simple illustration of two tables I have to store web pages:

```
Page
----
* PageId
CurrentRevisions -> PageRevisions.RevId

PageRevisions
-------------
* RevId
PageId -> Page.PageId
Title
Contents
```

The idea behind this is that I can have multiple page revisions stored in PageRevisions, while a Page is not much more than an ID and reference to a specific page revision.

Obviously, a page can only refer to one revisions as the "current" revision, whilst many revisions can refer back to a single page.

The problem is that this is a circular relationship.  In MySQL, with foreign keys enforced, I can't create Page without first creating a PageRevision, and I can't create a PageRevision without first creating a Page.

I could drop Page.CurrentRevisions and add PageRevisions.isCurrent, but I don't like that this design would allow more than one revision for a Page to be marked as current--I would prefer that the database design enforced that constraint (without triggers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a "deferred constraint," and, while it's supported in some database systems like PostgreSQL and Oracle, it's not in MySQL (as far as I know).  What it basically means is that relationships like your foreign key constraints aren't checked at each `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement, but only when the entire transaction is committed, so you're free to violate them during intermediate stages as long as you clean up the mess before you're done.

In your shoes, I'd probably recommend just making `CurrentRevisions` nullable.  Then you can create a placeholder `Page` with a null current revision, create your `PageRevision` referencing the placeholder page, and then set the current revision after both records are in the database.  You'd have to rely on your business logic to enforce consistency and make sure every page has a current revision, but that's not the end of the world.

Comment: Thanks very much.  Do you think this issue and MySQLs lack of support for DEFERRED CONSTRAINT is an indication I've chosen a poor design?  I wonder if I should create a third table to define the relationship between Page and PageRevision.

Comment: No, I think allowing nulls in your `CurrentRevisions` column and relying on business logic to keep things consistent is perfectly fine under the circumstances.  The recent trend for small-to-medium-sized applications, especially with things like ORM frameworks, is to rely more heavily on business rules for enforcement of data integrity anyway.  Just make sure to wrap everything in a transaction if you possibly can.

Comment: I should also add that you can still have the foreign key constraints in place even if you allow nulls, so things like validation and cascading deletes will still work.  The only danger is the short period of time where you have a record in the `Page` table with a null current revision, but that's a non-issue if you use a transaction.

Answer (score 2):

*Jeremy Todd provided a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16619789/533120) (+1 to him), I'd just like to make an additional point...*

Is the "current" the same thing as "latest"? If yes, then you can use an identifying relationship and the resulting composite key to naturally model that:

[image]

All the revisions of the same page have the same `PageRevision.PageId`, and their historical order within the page is determined by the integer `RevNo`. The latest revision is simply the one with the highest `RevNo` within its respective page.

Since [InnoDB tables are clustered](http://www.ovaistariq.net/521/understanding-innodb-clustered-indexes/), this structure will group the revisions of the same page physically close together. Retrieving all the revisions of the page will be potentially much quicker than in your original structure, and retrieving only the latest revision will be about as quick.

Data modification will also be quicker, since we have one less index.

---

> I could drop Page.CurrentRevisions and add PageRevisions.isCurrent, but I don't like that this design would allow more than one revision for a Page to be marked as current

Not that I'd recommend this approach, but the uniqueness of the "current" flag can be enforced declaratively, simply by using NULL instead of false:

```
CREATE TABLE PageRevision (
  RevId INT PRIMARY KEY,
  PageId INT NOT NULL,
  IsCurrent BIT CHECK (IsCurrent IS NULL OR (IsCurrent IS NOT NULL AND IsCurrent = 1)),
  UNIQUE (PageId, IsCurrent)
);

-- You can insert several "non current" revisions for the same page.
INSERT INTO PageRevision VALUES (1, 1, NULL);
INSERT INTO PageRevision VALUES (2, 1, NULL);
INSERT INTO PageRevision VALUES (3, 1, NULL);

-- You can insert one "current" revision in one page.
INSERT INTO PageRevision VALUES (4, 1, 1);

-- Or another "current" revision in a different page.
INSERT INTO PageRevision VALUES (5, 2, 1);

-- But not the second "current" revision in the same page.
-- The following violates the UNIQUE constraint:
INSERT INTO PageRevision VALUES (6, 1, 1);
```

*NOTE: MySQL parses but doesn't enforce the CHECK constraint above. As a consequence you could have one (unwanted) false flag per page in addition to one (useful) true flag per page.*

*NOTE 2: Because of the [peculiar nature of NULL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#Check_constraints_and_foreign_keys), the CHECK above could be rewritten simply as: `CHECK (IsCurrent = 1)`. When the flag is 0, the expression is false and the CHECK fails as expected. If the flag is 1 the expression is true and the CHECK passes. If the flag is NULL, the expression is NULL, and the CHECK **passes** (unlike WHERE which treats NULL as false). But I prefer to be a bit more explicit than that when dealing with NULLs.*

Comment: Thanks for the alternative suggestion.  There is good stuff in there that I wasn't fully aware of.